Reusing Chromium/Puppeteer instance on hot start using AWS Lambda
I am using Puppeteer/Chromium on AWS Lambda. In my lambda handler, I am launching/closing a Chromium instance every time the lambda is called.
Here is a simplified ES module example loosely based on @sparticuz/chromium documentation:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-core";
import chromium from "@sparticuz/chromium";

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  let browser = null;

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        ...chromium.args,
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--single-process',
      ],
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });

    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(event.url || 'https://example.com');

    return await page.title();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }
};

Launching Chromium takes some significant time and I'd like to reduce latency in case of warm/hot start. AWS documentation on Optimizing static initialization states that global variables retain their value between invocations in the same execution environment.
Can I move the browser to a global variable? If so, what are the best practices so the lambda instance is not stuck if the browser crash? I'd also like to prevent the exhausting memory (e.g. loading of an unbounded amount of pages) if the handler to not close gracefully.

Did you try making it global to see if it works? If the browser crashes, an exception should be thrown, so you can log the error and relaunch it. Avoiding an unbounded number of pages probably would be best with a worker task of some sort--enqueue the jobs into the worker.

Having the browser on top level, hence a top level await, you would also need the handler to be an ES module:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-node-js-es-modules-and-top-level-await-in-aws-lambda/
If your use case is monitoring, did you look into AWS CloudWatch Synthetic Canaries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html ?
Canaries come with pupeteer (or selenium) runtimes and are quite fast.

@ChristianBanfi I fixed the example to use an ES module. Also, the use-case is generating page screenshots and PDFs so Canaries does not fit.

@DurandA, with "exhausting memory if the handler to not close gracefully" you mean the lambda handler? "e.g. loading of an unbounded amount of pages", you have control over the amount of pages loaded, don't you? When using lambdas, you pay per allocated memory and lambda duration, no matter how much memory you are using.
How do you trigger the lambda function?

@ChristianBanfi The available memory is allocated in advance for each lambda instance. Since I want to reuse Chromium instances, I must ensure that every page that is opened will be closed otherwise the instance will exhaust memory over time.

@DurandA you can close pages directly: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.close

@ChristianBanfi There is some concerning documentation about Chromium sometimes opens up more pages than you ask for.: https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium?tab=readme-ov-file#im-experiencing-timeouts-or-failures-closing-chromium

@DurandA I see. Well, that note is quite vague "Chromium sometimes opens up more pages than you ask for." ... how much more? How do you trigger your Lambda Functions and how often do those run? ggorlen's comment is worth to look into, but it's quite a lot of effort. I would recommend, in general, as much error handling as possible, monitoring and alerting. Out Of Memory error handling in JavaScript is not straight forward. Usually the script simply stops and does not reach the error handling part. Note, even global browser variable gets removed if the lambda does not run for while.
